# Want to make a camera in Blender

Tags: camera, image

I am working on a game in UPBGE (Ver. 0.30.0), and I want to make a camera the way a photo camera works in the game, Iron Lung. I want it to be placed in front of the submarine I control, and allow me to take a picture and view it on an internal screen when I click a button. Bonus points if there's a way to make the picture look grungy.
[image: Something like this]
I kinda want it something like this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: i am not totally sure but shouldn't this be pretty easy with adding just a second camera and parenting? or what is exactly your problem here?

Comment: So is the camera clip a video or actually there in Blender? Could you explain the question a little?

Comment: In the game, it's set up in a way that the camera is not functional 24/7. You need to click a "take photograph" button in order to display the photo. The picture is of what's in front of you. I'm wondering how I should set it so that:-
1. It is displayed on a screen
2. Preferrably with a grunge filter
3. Just a picture, not a movie

Comment: IDK how you would do it in BGE but in Unreal you can get a Cameras viewpoint, use that to render a snapshot of what the camera sees, and then use that rendered image as a texture in a materials emissive input. I imagine it would be fairly similar in BGE as well.